# unknown escape sequence

Tags: c, строки, if, escape

пишет, что файл не найден, хотя я его создал. Уже пробовал писать `\\`, но по прежнему не работает, подскажите, что не так

```
void program1()
{
    FILE * a;
    int b;

    if(a = fopen("D:\lab9.txt","r") == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening lab.txt");
        exit(0);
    }



    while(b = fgetc(a) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", b);
    }
    fclose(a);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слэши надо экранировать `"D:\\lab9.txt"`

Comment: я так писал, по прежнему не работает. Программа просто не выполняется

Comment: @Aimin "По-прежнему не работает" - это не эквивалентно тому, что "unknown escape sequence".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я добавил скрин, посмотрите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в этом предложении

```
if(a = fopen("D:\lab9.txt","r") == NULL)
```

сразу же две ошибки.

Должно быть

```
if( ( a = fopen("D:\\lab9.txt","r") ) == NULL)
```

То есть присвоение должно быть заключено в круглые скобки, должен быть правильно указан ескапе символ.

Аналогичная ошибка с приоритетом операций и в этом предложении

```
while(b = fgetc(a) != EOF)
```

Должно быть

```
while( ( b = fgetc(a) ) != EOF)
```